# How to call Azure AD protected API in Xamarin.forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-active-directory

Here Is What I'm Doing.
I Have Use MSAL authentication in Xamarin forms app. I have Successfully login and I have also get the access Token which I used to access SharePoint WebAPI. Now I have created Mobile app Service in `Azure App Service`. When I'm going to access this protected API with Azure Existing Authentication with the Same token, the Response is 401 unauthorized. Anyone help me how I should now call this Azure Protected API

Comment: You'd need to acquire another access token for your API. You'll need to use a scope id for that. Define at least one in the API app registration in Azure AD Expose API tab and assign it to your Xamarin app registration in API permissions tab.

Comment: yes i have added this scope"user_impersonation" in permission  and also call api again with this scope  and get a token which i test in jwt.io it has a scp value butt again calling AZ protected api end point 401 unauthorized .

Comment: @juunas I didn't know where i'm Making mistake.

Comment: Sounds like the token should be valid. It's possible authentication is configured incorrectly on the app service.

Comment: Can you give me Any Reference so that i verify configration?@juunas

Comment: They have some reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app